# First Step Analysis of a Markov Chain process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have a Markov Chain transition probability matrix as the following. 
The possible states are $\{0,1,2\}$
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
0.6 & 0.2 & 0.2 \\ 0.2 & 0.5 & 0.3 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The question asks me the last non-absorbing state is $0$, starting from state $X_{0} = 0$.

I attempt the following: I let $T = \min\{n \geq 0, X_{n} = 2 \}$ be time of absorption and consider $u_{i} = P(X_{T-1} = 0 | X_{0} = i)$
I set up the equation of using First Step Analysis:

$$
u_{0} = 0.6 u_0 + 0.2u_1 + 0.2u_2
$$

$$
u_{1} = 0.2 u_0 + 0.5 u_1 + 0.3 u_2
$$

$$
u_2  = 1
$$

I solve this and get $u_1 = 44/50$ and $u_0 = 47/50$. But I checked the answer in the back it is said that $u_0 = u_1 = 1$. Does I misunderstand the statement to express in terms of $u_{i}$?

Comment: You've done something wrong because we should have $u_0+u_1=1$. The answer $u_0=u_1=1$ doesn't make sense for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this $\texttt R$ code to simulate the process:

```
rm(list=ls())

N <- 10000

X <- rep(0, N)

for(i in 1:N) {
  state <- 0

  while(state!=2) {
    U <- runif(1)
    if(state==0) {
      if(U <0.6)
        state <- 0
      else if(U <0.8)
        state <- 1
      else {
        X[i] <- 0
        state <- 2
      }
    }
    else {
      if(U<0.2)
        state <- 0
      else if(U < 0.7)
        state <- 1
      else {
        X[i] <- 1
        state <- 2
      }
    }
  }
}

cat(sprintf("P(last non-absorbing state=0) = %f\n", length(which(X==0))/N))
```

This gives an approximate probability of $0.62$ that the last non-absorbing state is $0$. I hope it is useful.

Comment: Can you explain this in terms of First Step Analysis?

Comment: It isn't a first-step analysis. It simulates the process, starting at state $0$ until it reaches state $2$, and records the last state visited before reaching state $2$. It does this 10000 times (you can increase $N$ for less variance on the point estimate of the mean) and outputs the fraction of times the last state visited was state $0$0.